# Setting variables with exec inside a function

Tags: python, string, function, variables, exec

I just started self teaching Python, and I need a little help with this script:

```
old_string = "didnt work"   
new_string = "worked"

def function():
    exec("old_string = new_string")     
    print(old_string) 

function()
```

I want to get it so `old_string = "worked"`.

Comment: What's the point of this? Why do you want to use exec here?

Comment: "I just started self teaching Python.." sounds like they're is just trying to wrap their head around a new language...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're almost there. You're trying to modify a global variable so you have to add the `global` statement:

```
old_string = "didn't work"
new_string = "worked"

def function():
    exec("global old_string; old_string = new_string")
    print(old_string)

function()
```

If you run the following version, you'll see what happened in your version:

```
old_string = "didn't work"
new_string = "worked"

def function():
    _locals = locals()
    exec("old_string = new_string", globals(), _locals)
    print(old_string)
    print(_locals)

function()
```

output:

```
didn't work
{'old_string': 'worked'}
```

The way you ran it, you ended up trying to modify the function's local variables in `exec`, which is basically undefined behavior. See the warning in the [`exec` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> **Note:** The default *locals* act as described for function `locals()` below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function `exec()` returns.

and the related warning on [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

> **Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Comment: Is there a way to modify it in the scope of the calling function?

Comment: @SarcasticSully there is no calling function here..  If you wonder about something tangentially associated with the question, or answer, you should ask a new question (with the proper context, code samples, etc.) Leaving new questions in comments of 3 year old answers isn't likely to be helpful for anyone...

Comment: Rather than add a `global` statement, you can simply set the namespaces: `exec('old_string = new_string', globals(), globals())`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you do that (`exec('..', globals(), globals())`) any variable created in the exec becomes a global -- probably not what you want?

Comment: Yes, and that could be the goal. Most people forget about the ability to specify the namespaces (including new dictionaries), if you don’t want all names as globals using a custom namespace and then extracting what you need afterwards might be the better option anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's starting to sound like an answer ;-)  While I agree with your argument in general (modulo Python leaking loop variables), I stand by my answer in this particular context for this particular user. (I've upvoted khelwood's answer since it's a useful insight).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, I see the question has been heavily edited.. Check the history for context.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative way of having `exec` update your global variables from inside a function is to pass `globals()` into it.

```
>>> def function(command):
...    exec(command, globals())
...
>>> x = 1
>>> function('x += 1')
>>> print(x)
2
```

Unlike `locals()`, updating the `globals()` dictionary is expected always to update the corresponding global variables.

Comment: Try `function("[t for t in range(5)]")`, then `print(t)`... Maybe too many unintended consequences?

Comment: @thebjorn I get `NameError: name 't' is not defined`, which is what I would expect. Are you using an old version of Python before they fixed the variables-escaping-comprehensions bug?

Comment: Yes 2.7 all the way! (*sigh*).  Did they fix the for-loop variable escape too?

Comment: No, if I understand you correctly. I think that's intended behaviour.