# Reason for error when using exec() within a function in python

Tags: python-3.x, exec

If I make a code like:

```
lists = ["a='1'", "b='2'", "c=a+b"]
returned_list = []
for x in lists:
    exec(x)
print(c)
```

It works, and It print "12".  but, If I use exec() in function:

```
lists = ["a='1'", "b='2'", "c=a+b"]
def test(lst):
    for x in lists:
        exec(x)

    print(c)
test(lists)
```

It returns `NameError: name 'c' is not defined`. How could I use exec() in function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exec() not working inside function python3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100196/exec-not-working-inside-function-python3-x)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a new variable in a function, you are actually assigning a variable in a scope which will be closed after the function is closed.
Imagine it as a bubble with an item inside, which after the bubble blows, the item blows and disappears as well. It means, using exec() in a **function** would create a temporary local variable. But since functions have a predefined code, adding new variables to them without changing the code directly, would **not** be possible. in that case we need to use **global** keyword for each new variable in exec to make the variable save in the *main* and not in function. Therefor, your list would like this:

`lists = ["global a\na='1'"]`

also I'm not quite sure if you like the output of *a+b* be 12, if not, you can just remove the single quotes around each number such as `"a=1"` to make them integers

for further information check [this](https://www.quickstart.com/blog/understanding-functions-global-variables-and-local-variables-in-python-programming/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423668/11609880)