# assignment within exec in python

Tags: python, variable-assignment, python-exec

I am trying to build calculator using PyQt5 and I get string which I need to evaluate and assign it to a variable so that I can Pass that variable to widgets as an answer . So far I can evaluate the expression but can't assing it . How can I do that ? so far I have following code:-

```
# this functions gets called when Enter is pressed
def etrp(self):
    eqn =  self.sender().text()                  #I get string like '23+4'
    eqn1 = "{0} = {1}".format("global x",eqn)    #I make it x = 23+4
    x = 0
    exec(eqn1)                                   # I get error here
    print(x)
    #some code .....
```

When I try to run it without global, it runs without error but x remains 0 and If I ran it like this I get this error:-

```
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
global x = 12+32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/orayan/Development/Python/Calculator/calculator.py", line 11, in etrp
    exec(eqn1)
  File "<string>", line 1
    global x = 12+32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[1]    19185 abort (core dumped)  ./main.py
```

I am very new to python So can't figure out whats going on

Comment: 1. Please show us more of the traceback. 2. If you are new to Python, consider familiarizing yourself with the language more before using PyQt5. 3. Don't use global variables.

Comment: @Coal_ 1. I had added complete output .2. I agree But I am very familiar with Qt in C++ thus ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
global x = 5
```

is not valid python code.

If you want to assign to a global variable `x`, you should write

```
global x
x = 5
```

Try changing your code as

```
global x
eqn1 = "{0} = {1}".format("x",eqn)
x = 0
exec(eqn1, globals())
```

To modify global variables with exec, you need to use [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function.

EDIT: Add globals() function.

Comment: X's value is now 0

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, `exec` and `eval` are evil. When you use them on a non sanitized string, you implicitely accept to execute almost any Python expression...

But that have not exactly same usages: `exec` is meant to execute some code, while `eval` will return a value. Here the correct way would be:

```
x = eval(eqn)
```

That is not a correct usage of a global variable anyway because it is only used to get a value from a call, so the correct way is to have the function to return the value, hence `eval` instead of `exec`.

But remember: `eval` is *evil* so **never use that in production code**.

Answer (score 0):

On the question of why it doesn't work when one tries to modify a local variable, this is specifically forbidden.  [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168282/setting-variables-with-exec-inside-a-function)

Comment: Please don't just post urls.

Comment: @mate00 I feel justified.  I explained completely where the problem arises (in the first case given by OP) and gave a reference.  The fact that the explanation is brief is no reason to deride it. I've noticed that StackExch likes people to point to other posts within StExch when they deal with the same problem, so I did. Who could ask for more?