# How do you assign local variables within a function using exec?

Tags: python, scope

I have a function with an unspecified number of input strings which are intended to be variable names. For example

```
def f(*args):
    for arg in args:
        exec('{} = 1'.format(arg))

    return a

f('a', 'b')
```

When running the code, I recieve the following error

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

---

How do I assign local variables for the function which are to be manipulated or returned? The solution provided in this [similar but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168282/setting-variables-with-exec-inside-a-function) requires creating the variables outside the function, i.e. adding them to the global namespace, but that is not what I want.

Comment: You cannot add variables to the local namespace; its contents were fixed at compile time.

Comment: You don't. It's bad practice to begin with. There is no need for dynamic variables