# How may I dynamically create global variables within a function based on input in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, global

I'm trying to create a function that returns a **dynamically-named** list of columns. Usually I can manually name the list, but I now have 100+ csv files to work with.

My goal:

1. Function creates a list, **and names it based on dataframe name**
2. Created list is callable outside of the function

I've done my research, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463306/how-does-exec-work-with-locals#:%7E:text=This%20issue%20is,need%20to%20do:) from an earlier post came very close to helping me.

Here is what I've adapted

```
def test1(dataframe):
    # Using globals() to get dataframe name
    df_name = [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is dataframe][0]
    
    # Creating local dictionary to use exec function
    local_dict = {}
    
    # Trying to generate a name for the list, based on input dataframe name 
    name = 'col_list_' + df_name
    exec(name + "=[]", globals(), local_dict)

    # So I can call this list outside the function
    name = local_dict[name]
    
    for feature in dataframe.columns:
        # Append feature/column if >90% of values are missing
        if dataframe[feature].isnull().mean() >= 0.9:
            name.append(feature)
            
    return name
```

To ensure the list name changes **based on the DataFrame supplied** to the function, I named the list using:

 `name = 'col_list_' + df_name`

The problem comes when I try to make this list accessible outside the function:

 `name = local_dict[name]`.

I cannot find away to assign a dynamic list name to the local dictionary, so I am forced to always call `name` outside the function to return the list. I want the list to be named based on the dataframe input (eg. col_list_df1, col_list_df2, col_list_df99).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168282/setting-variables-with-exec-inside-a-function) was very helpful, but it seems specific to variables.

 `global 'col_list_' + df_name` returns a syntax error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not utilize pandas to read each csv file into it's own data frame.  This will define the column headings based on the csv file.  You can then keep a list of data frames and process them as you see fit.

Comment: Actually I've already read in each csv file into its own dataframe. From there, I'm trying to make a function that takes in these dataframes, and returns a list of columns names. Additionally, I was hoping the function can name the list based on the dataframe name.