# Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python

```
def plotx(arg):
    m=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
    l=arg.split(",")
    l1=l[0]
    l1=l1.replace("?","m")
    l2=l[1]
    l2=l2.replace("?","m")
    print(l1)
    print(l2)
    exec("x ="+l1)
    exec("y ="+l2)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
  

@client.command()
async def plot(ctx,arg):
    plotx(arg)
```

Error Side

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\Arda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "D:\Users\Arda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "D:\Users\Arda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Im getting this error how ı can fix it?

Comment: Also I wrote this code in different file and it works

Comment: What? exec("x ="+l1)? Did you mean x=l1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting variables with exec inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168282/setting-variables-with-exec-inside-a-function)

Comment: No .l1 is like np.sin (m). And exec ("x =" + l1) ==>  x = np.sin (m) # np.sin(m) calculated with exec function

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168282/setting-variables-with-exec-inside-a-function), performing `exec("var = ...")` is highly not recommended. Simply doing `x = l1` as quamrana suggests, should fix the error.

Comment: Hang on...  at ("x=" + l1)  `l1` may have an `'m'` in it,  that can't be a value that would be valid to assign to `x`.

Comment: Ah, I guess since `l1` is a string, if it's something like "[1, 2, 3]", then you might want to use [`ast.literal_eval` or `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) instead (prefer the former).

Comment: Probably what I want.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not assigning any value to the `x` and `y` variables that your code is calling in `plt.plot(x, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
l=arg.split(",")
l1=l[0]
l1=l1.replace("?","m")
l2=l[1]
l2=l2.replace("?","m")
exec("x ="+l1)
exec("y ="+l2)
```

with

```
l=arg.split(",")
x=l[0].replace("?","m")
y=l[1].replace("?","m")
```

even clearer would be:

```
arg = arg.replace("?","m")
x,y = arg.split(",")
```

you could make it a one-liner but I think that sacrifices clarity.

Even better would be to just accept x and y as arguments in the first place!

Comment: My purpose is  for example l1=np.sin(?) when I wrote exec("x ="+l1) x will be equal to np.sin(?) array

Comment: You know you can pass functions as arguments?