# using exec function in function and defining variable

Tags: python

When I run this code I don't get a error.
I'm trying to calculate l1 and put into variable a.

```
m=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
l1="np.sin(m)"
exec(f"a ={l1}")
print(a)
```

When I run this I get a error.Why?

```
def g():
    m=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
    l1="np.sin(m)"
    exec(f"a ={l1}")
    print(a)
g()
```

Error:name "a" is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Check link: [Setting variables with exec inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168282/setting-variables-with-exec-inside-a-function)

```
def g():
    m=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
    l1="np.sin(m)"
    exec(f"global a; a={l1}")
    print(a)
g()
```